# Circuit construction for Hamiltonian simulation

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, hamiltonian-simulation

I would like to know how to design a quantum circuit that given a Hermitian matrix $\hat{H}$ and time $t$, maps $|\psi\rangle$ to $e^{i\hat{H}t} |\psi\rangle$.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: There are many advanced algorithms for compiling a Hamiltonian into a series of gates; are you looking for a summary of some of the simpler approaches, or a list of resources to start you off?

Answer (score 27):

**An approach for Hamiltonian simulation:**

Any Hermitian (Hamiltonian) matrix $H$ can be decomposed by the sum of Pauli products with real coefficients (see this [thread](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8725/can-arbitrary-matrices-be-decomposed-using-the-pauli-basis)). An example of 3 qubit Hamiltonian:

$$H = 11 \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z + 7 \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_x - 5\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_x \otimes \sigma_y$$

The final circuit for $e^{iHt}$ can be simulated via Trotter decomposition (chapter 4.1 from the paper [[1](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)]):

$$e^{iHt} \approx \big(\prod_k e^{i c_k P_k t/N }\big)^{N}$$

where $t$ is a parameter that can have either positive or negative values, $P_k$ are the Pauli terms, $c_k$ are the coefficients of the corresponding $P_k$s, $H = \sum_k c_k P_k$, $N$ is the Trotter number. By increasing $N$ it is possible to decrease the error of the Trotter decomposition as much as desired [[1](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)]. If all $P_k$ Pauli terms are commuting to each other, then we can take $N = 1$ (no Trotter decomposition is needed). For this simulation, we need to know how to simulate individual Pauli products $e^{iP_k t}$. Let's start with the simplest one $e^{i \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \otimes ... \otimes \sigma_z t}$ (chapter 4.2 of the paper [[1](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)]). Here is the circuit for $e^{i \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t}$ from the paper [[1](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)]

[image]

Here $R_z$'s argument is $-2t$ ($R_z(-2t) = e^{i\sigma_z t}$). Before showing why this is true let's introduce 2 formulas that we will us. 4.2 exercise from the textbook [[2](https://www.cambridge.org/am/academic/subjects/physics/quantum-physics-quantum-information-and-quantum-computation/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-10th-anniversary-edition?format=HB)]: Let $t$ be a real number and $A$ a matrix such that $A^2 = I$. Then

$$e^{iA t} = \cos(t) I + i \sin(t) A$$

For all Pauli terms, this $P_k^2 =I$ is true. So we can use this formula. For CNOT gate we have:

$$\mathrm{CNOT} = |0\rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I + |1\rangle \langle 1 | \otimes \sigma_x$$

By taking these formulas into account let's show that the circuit implements the $e^{i \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t}$ Pauli term:

\begin{align*}
e^{i \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t} = \cos(t) I + i \sin(t) \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z 
\end{align*}

The circuit:

\begin{align*}
&\mathrm{CNOT} \left(I \otimes e^{i \sigma_z  t}\right) \mathrm{CNOT}= 
\big[|0\rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I + |1\rangle \langle 1 | \otimes \sigma_x \big] \\ 
&\big[ \cos(t) I\otimes I + i \sin(t) I \otimes \sigma_z \big]
\big[|0\rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I + |1\rangle \langle 1 | \otimes \sigma_x \big] = \\
&= \cos(t) I + i \sin(t) \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z 
\end{align*}

So, the circuit implements what we want:

$$
e^{i \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t} =\mathrm{CNOT} \left(I \otimes e^{i \sigma_z  t}\right) \mathrm{CNOT}
$$

The circuit for the $e^{i \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t}$ Pauli term from the same paper [[1](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)]:

[image]

This also can be shown the same way. Moreover, this solution can be generalized for $e^{i \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \otimes ... \otimes \sigma_z t}$ Pauli term.

Now, what if we have one $\sigma_x$ in the tensor product $P = P_1 \otimes \sigma_x^{(n)} \otimes P_2$, where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are also Pauli products, $n$ is the qubit number. Note that:

\begin{align*}
e^{iP_1 \otimes \sigma_x^{(n)} \otimes P_2t} &= \cos(t) I + i \sin(t) P_1 \otimes \sigma_x^{(n)} \otimes P_2 = \\
&= \cos(t) I + i \sin(t) P_1 \otimes \left(H \sigma_z^{(n)} H\right) \otimes P_2 = \\
&= H^{(n)} e^{iP_1 \otimes \sigma_z^{(n)} \otimes P_2t} H^{(n)}
\end{align*}

where $H^{(n)}$ is the Hadamard gate acting on $n$th qubit. The same can be shown for $\sigma_y$:

\begin{align*}
e^{iP_1 \otimes \sigma_y^{(n)} \otimes P_2t} = H_y^{(n)} e^{iP_1 \otimes \sigma_z^{(n)} \otimes P_2t} H_y^{(n)}
\end{align*}

where $H_y$ is a self-inverse gate (that was suggested [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11391/9459)), which has this nice property $\sigma_y = H_y \sigma_z H_y$:

$$H_y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -i \\
i & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, we can simulate any Pauli term. For example, the circuit for $e^{i \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_x}$ will look like this:

$$e^{i \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_x} = \big[ H_y \otimes H_y \otimes H \big]  e^{i \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z} \big[H_y \otimes  H_y \otimes H\big]  $$

[image]

By applying appropriate rotations we can bring any Pauli term simulation problem to the simplest $e^{i \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \otimes ... \otimes \sigma_z t}$ Pauli term simulation problem, which solution we already know. With this approach, we can simulate any Pauli term, thus also any Hermitian operator.

---

**Addition**: $I$ operators in the Pauli product terms

Here we will try to show that we can ignore $I$ operators in the Pauli products when we try to construct circuits for them. For example, we will take $\sigma_z \otimes I \otimes \sigma_z$ operator and show that we can forget about the second qubit and simulate the circuit for $e^{i\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t}$ applied on the first and third qubits. We should proof that:

$$e^{i\sigma_z \otimes I \otimes \sigma_z t} = CNOT^{(1,3)}R_z^{(3)}(-2t)CNOT^{(1,3)}$$

For the left side we have:

$$e^{i\sigma_z \otimes I \otimes \sigma_z t} = \cos(t) I \otimes I \otimes I + \sin(t) \sigma_z \otimes I \otimes \sigma_z$$

For the right side:

\begin{align}
&CNOT^{(1,3)}R_z^{(3)}(-2t)CNOT^{(1,3)} = \big[| 0 \rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I \otimes I + | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | \otimes I \otimes X  \big] \\
&\big[ I \otimes I \otimes \big( \cos(t) I + i \sin(t) \sigma_z \big) \big]
\big[ | 0 \rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I \otimes I  + | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | \otimes I \otimes X \big]=
\\
&= \cos(t) I \otimes I \otimes I + \sin(t) \sigma_z \otimes I \otimes \sigma_z
\end{align}

So, they are equal to each other: we can forget about $I$ operator for constructing a circuit in this case. This solution can be generalized for $n$ $I$ operators between two $\sigma_z$ terms.

Also, let's proof that $I \otimes P \otimes I$ can be simulated by $e^{i I \otimes P \otimes I t} = I \otimes e^{i P t} \otimes I$, where $P$ is some Pauli product:

\begin{align}
&e^{i I \otimes P \otimes I t} = \cos(t) I \otimes I \otimes I + i\sin(t) I \otimes P \otimes I 
\\
&= I \otimes \big( \cos(t) I + i \sin(t) P \big) \otimes = I \otimes e^{i P t} \otimes I
\end{align}

In this manner, it can be shown for general cases that we can ignore $I$ operators when we simulate Pauli terms in the quantum circuits.

---

Qiskit implementations of the ideas described here can be found in this [tutorial](https://github.com/DavitKhach/quantum-algorithms-tutorials/blob/master/Hamiltonian_simulation.ipynb).

[[1](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)]  [J.D. Whitfield,  J. Biamonte, and  A. Aspuru-Guzik,
Molecular Physics, "Simulation of electronic structure Hamiltonians using
quantum computers" (2011)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)

[[2](https://www.cambridge.org/am/academic/subjects/physics/quantum-physics-quantum-information-and-quantum-computation/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-10th-anniversary-edition?format=HB)] [M.A. Nielsen, I.L. Chuang, Cambridge University Press New York, "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information: 10th Anniversary Edition
10th" (2011)](https://www.cambridge.org/am/academic/subjects/physics/quantum-physics-quantum-information-and-quantum-computation/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-10th-anniversary-edition?format=HB)

Comment: Can you explain this in detail\begin{align*}
e^{i \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t} &= \cos(t) I + i \sin(t) \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z =\\
&= \mathrm{CNOT} e^{i \sigma_z \otimes I  t} \mathrm{CNOT} 
= \mathrm{CNOT} \left(e^{i \sigma_z t} \otimes I\right) \mathrm{CNOT}
\end{align*}

Comment: Yep, I tried to explain it more explicitly. @Omkar, does it look better?

Comment: I edited the answer with more detailed explanations. Now I don't have that step, instead, I have 3 steps in my answer. The first step is to describe $e^{i\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t}$  by using the Euler-like formula for Pauli matrices. In the second and third steps, I show that the presented circuit is equal to the $e^{i\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t}$. Also, I changed/corrected some notations.

Comment: @David Khachatryan, I got it. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi Davit, thanks for very clear introduction to Hamiltonian simulation. However, could you please show how a circuit look like in case there is a unit matrix in tensor product, for example $\sigma_z \otimes I \otimes I$? These terms appear in Ising Hamiltonians for spin glasses. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MartinVesely, I will try: $e^{i \sigma_z \otimes I \otimes I t} = \cos(t) I \otimes I \otimes I + i \sin(t) \sigma_z \otimes I \otimes I  = (\cos(t) I + i \sin(t) \sigma_z) \otimes I \otimes I = R_z(-2t) \otimes I \otimes I$. Martin is this answers to your question?

Comment: @MartinVesely, in the answer, I added a part about $I$ operators in the Pauli terms.

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan: Thank you very much for help. It is a perfect guide how to implement Hamiltonian simulation.

Comment: If we want to prepare a state $H\ket{\psi}$, is it the same than $e^{iH}\ket{\psi}$?

Comment: @CésarLeonardoClementeLópez, no it is not the same. For example, If $|\psi_E \rangle$ is an eigenstate of the Hermitian operator $H$, then $H |\psi_E \rangle = E |\psi_E \rangle$ and $e^{iHt} |\psi_E \rangle = e^{iEt} |\psi_E \rangle$, where $E$ is the corresponding eigenvalue.

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan: Superb answer! Can this be extended to the problem of simulating $e^{Ht}$ where $H$ is Hermitian and $t$ is real?

Comment: @thespaceman, I am not sure about how one can somehow (in some sense) simulate $e^{Ht}$, but I am sure that there are no circuits for not unitary operators ($e^{Ht}$ is not unitary in general).

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan is there a simple way to validate . \begin{align*}
&\mathrm{CNOT} \left(I \otimes e^{i \sigma_z  t}\right) \mathrm{CNOT}= 
\big[|0\rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I + |1\rangle \langle 1 | \otimes \sigma_x \big] \\ 
&\big[ \cos(t) I\otimes I + i \sin(t) I \otimes \sigma_z \big]
\big[|0\rangle \langle 0 | \otimes I + |1\rangle \langle 1 | \otimes \sigma_x \big] = \\
&= \cos(t) I + i \sin(t) \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z 
\end{align*}? For more difficult unitaries it’s hard I repeat this, right?

Answer (score 8):

**Controlled version of $e^{iHt}$:**

Often in the algorithms (e.g. in HHL or PEA), we want to construct not the circuit for Hamiltonian simulation $e^{iHt}$, but the controlled version of it. For this, we will use the result obtained from the previous [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11373/9459). First of all, note that if we have $ABC$ circuit, where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are operators, then the controlled version of that circuit will equal $cA$ $cB$ $cC$, where $c$ denotes control version of an operator. From the previous [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11373/9459) we know that $e^{iHt}$ consists of $e^{iPt}$ terms, where $P$ is some Pauli product. So, for solving the problem we should find a way for constructing controlled versions of $e^{iPt}$ terms. Here is a general form for the circuit that implements any given $e^{iPt}$ and the controlled version of it (like was done similarly in this paper [[1](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)]):

[image]

where $O_i$ are gates from this set $\{I, H, H_y\}$, and they are chosen differently for each Pauli term (see the previous [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11373/9459)). The right circuit in the picture implements the controlled version of the $e^{iPt}$, because, if control qubit is in the $|0\rangle$ state the $R_z$ gate will not work and the rest gates will cancel each other (they are self-inverse gates).

When we are talking about the controlled version of the circuit we shouldn't forget about $e^{iIt}$ term (the global phase in the $e^{iHt}$). We should also construct a circuit that implements controlled version of $e^{iIt}$. Let's call it controlled-global phase ($CGP$) gate and try to implement it. The effect of $CGP$ for controlled qubit $\alpha|0_c\rangle + \beta|1_c\rangle$ acting on multi-qubit $| \psi \rangle$ state:

$$ CGP \left( \alpha|0_c\rangle + \beta|1_c\rangle \right) |\psi\rangle = \left( \alpha|0_c\rangle + e^{it}\beta|1_c\rangle \right) |\psi\rangle$$

where $t$ is the phase. This action can be done just by one Qiskit's $u1$ phase gate acting on the control qubit [[2](https://www.cambridge.org/am/academic/subjects/physics/quantum-physics-quantum-information-and-quantum-computation/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-10th-anniversary-edition?format=HB)]:

$$u1(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{it}\end{pmatrix}$$

[[1](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)]  [J.D. Whitfield,  J. Biamonte, and  A. Aspuru-Guzik,
Molecular Physics, "Simulation of electronic structure Hamiltonians using
quantum computers" (2011)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)

[[2](https://www.cambridge.org/am/academic/subjects/physics/quantum-physics-quantum-information-and-quantum-computation/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-10th-anniversary-edition?format=HB)] [M.A. Nielsen, I.L. Chuang, Cambridge University Press New York, "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information: 10th Anniversary Edition
10th" (2011)](https://www.cambridge.org/am/academic/subjects/physics/quantum-physics-quantum-information-and-quantum-computation/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-10th-anniversary-edition?format=HB)