# Definitions of $D_y$ gate in Hamiltonian simulation: are they the same?

Tags: quantum-gate, hamiltonian-simulation, pauli-gates, hadamard

I'm reading a Hamiltonian simulation example proposed in [this paper](https://quantum-journal.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/q-2020-09-12-322.pdf). From their notation, the operator $D_y$ (sometimes it's called $H_y$) serves the function to diagonalize the Pauli matrix $\sigma_y(Y)$ (the corresponding circuit is illustrated below):
$$
D_y\ (or\ H_y)=HSX=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
i & 1\\
-i & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\quad\quad [A] 
$$
[image]

However, unlike $D_x$, which is the Hadamard gate, I found $D_y$ is sometimes written in different ways, like in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11391/12334) by @Craig Gidney:

$$
D_y\ (or\ H_{YZ}) = \frac{Y+Z}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -i\\
i & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\quad\quad [B] 
$$

and in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11403/12334) by @Davit Khachatryan:

$$
D_y\ (or \ 'Y'_{not\ pauli\ here}) = U_2(0,\pi/2) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -i\\
1 & i
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\quad\quad [C] 
$$

Thus I'm wondering are those different versions of $D_y$ the same thing? Are they essentially all belong to $U_2$ gate?

Also, when should we use two $U_3$ gates outside of the CNOT gates to perform the time-evolution simulation (like in [this case](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14595/12334), the answer from @KAJ226)?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A and C are technically the same thing, they only differ by a global phase, which makes no difference.

B is technically different, but serves the same purpose. Note that if
$UYU^\dagger=Z$, then $$R_zUYU^\dagger R_z^\dagger=R_zZR_z^\dagger=ZR_zR_z^\dagger=Z$$
so if the only effect you're interested in is the diagonalisation of $Y$, there is a freedom of an arbitrary $Z$ rotation $R_z=e^{i\theta Z/2}$ in the definition of your unitary.

In the end, we have the relations
$$
D^C=-iD^A=S^\dagger D^B.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are all of the definitions serve the same purpose to diagonalize $Y$? Could you explain a bit more about how the definition of B is different from that of A? Thanks:)

Comment: It's just a different matrix that achieves the same result of diagonalising $Y$. Which should you pick? whichever you can implement more easily.