# How do I find the matrix and circuit equivalent to this transformation?

Tags: quantum-gate

First I would like to find the matrix corresponding to the transformation and then implement it with rotational gates. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix for $\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z$:

$$\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z = 
\begin{pmatrix}  
1&0&0&0 \\
0&-1&0&0 \\
0&0&-1&0 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The matrix for $e^{-i\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t}$, where $t$ is some parameter:

$$e^{-i\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t} = 
\begin{pmatrix}  
e^{-i t}&0&0&0 \\
0&e^{i t}&0&0 \\
0&0&e^{i t}&0 \\
0&0&0&e^{-i t} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

The circuit for this operator (like described in this [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2011.552441)):

[image]

where $R_z$'s argument is $2t$. An explicit explanation about why this circuit implements the operator mentioned above can be found [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11373/9459). Or can be seen after doing matrix multiplication for the gates presented in the circuit:

$$
\text{CNOT} \cdot I \otimes R_z(2t) \cdot \text{CNOT} = \\ =
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}  
e^{-i t}&0&0&0 \\
0&e^{i t}&0&0 \\
0&0&e^{-i t}&0 \\
0&0&0&e^{i t}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix} 
= e^{-i\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z t}
$$