# Is there a tool to get the quantum circuit corresponding to a sparse matrix?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, circuit-construction, hamiltonian-simulation

If I know a sparse matrix, is there any tool that allows me to get the corresponding quantum circuit directly?

If not what should I do?

For example，I want to try hamilton simulation and I have the sparse matrix. How can I get the corresponding quantum circuit? By code or by some software? Or get enough training?

I'm new in this field.

Need your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning Hamiltonian simulation, you can find very useful guide in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5567/circuit-construction-for-hamiltonian-simulation).

General approach to quantum circuit construction is explained in paper [Elementary gates for quantum computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016).

Also paper [Optimal Quantum Circuits for General Two-Qubit Gates](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308006) can be helpful.