# Good book/paper for finding an ansatz via Trotterization?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, resource-request

Is there a good book or paper where they describe how to get the ansatz and gates from a Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I will do my best to answer from my understanding of your question:*

I am assuming you mean something like Unitary Coupled Cluster variational form where it is implemented the exponential to the initial state $|\psi \rangle$
$$ e^{T - T^\dagger} $$
here $T$ is the cluster operator, which, when acting on $|\psi$, produces a linear combination of excited determinants from the reference state. It can be written as
$$ T = \sum T_i$$
where $T_1$ is the operator for all single excitation, $T_2$ is the operator for all double excitation, and so forth.

$$T_1 = \sum_{i \in occupied} \sum_{\alpha \in Virtual} t_{\alpha}^i a^\dagger_{\alpha} a_i $$

$$T_2 = \dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{i,j \in occupied} \sum_{\alpha,\beta \in Virtual} t_{\alpha \beta}^{ij} a^\dagger_{\alpha} a^\dagger_{\beta} a_ia_j $$
$$ \vdots $$
$$T_n = \dfrac{1}{(n!)^2}\sum_{i_1, i_2 \cdots ,i_n \in occupied} \sum_{\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \cdots ,\alpha_n \in Virtual} t_{\alpha_1 \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n}^{i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_n} a^\dagger_{\alpha_1} a^\dagger_{\alpha_2} \cdots a^\dagger_{\alpha_n} a_{i_1}a_{i_2}\cdots a_{i_n} $$

If you only pick $T_1$ and $T_2$ then you have what called as UCCSD variational form, which [can be implemented very easily through Qiskit.](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.chemistry.components.variational_forms.UCCSD.html)

---

To understand how to convert exponential of matrix into quantum gates through Trotter, I would suggest you to look at [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5567/circuit-construction-for-hamiltonian-simulation?noredirect=1&lq=1).   In that answer, there are two very good references that you should look into.

I also suggest this paper:

[Strategies for quantum computing molecular energies using the unitary
coupled cluster ansatz.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02691)

---

If this is not what you are looking for then edit your question or leave a comment so I understand what you are looking for. This way I might be able to give you some better references.