# How to implement the Mixer of Quantum Alternating Operator Ansatz for Max-Independent-Set

Tags: programming, mathematics, hamiltonian-simulation, vqe, qaoa

I am trying to implement the Mixer of the Max-Independent Set from The Quantum Alternating Operator Ansatz.
From this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.03489.pdf in Chapter 4.2 page 15 to 17.

For every verice $v$ in the Graph this operator $H_{CX,v}$ is definded. ($nbhd(v)$ are all the neighbors of v)
\begin{align*}
    H_{CX,v} &= X_{v} H_{NOR(x_{nbhd(v)})} \\
    &= 2^{-D_{v}}X_{v}\prod_{w \in nbhd(v)}(I + Z_{w})\\
\end{align*}

Then the operators for all vertices are summed up.
Are there any rules how to sum up operators?
$$H_{CX} = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}H_{CX,v_{i}}$$

After that the exponential of the Matrix is calculated.
I have no clue how to do that.
$$U_{sim-CX}(\beta) = e^{-i\beta H_{CX}}$$

Should I maybe do a Hamiltonian-simulation or are there other ways for doing this?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Yes, but you can simulate it with Trotter approximation. Look at this answer: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5567/circuit-construction-for-hamiltonian-simulation  Afterward, you will see that it is not so bad to construct a circuit to do such simulation.

Comment: @KAJ226 Thankyou :)  So you think that a Hamiltonian simulation is what Hadfield indendet in the paper? (if you have read the paper)

Comment: In a sense, yes. Hamiltonian simulation is essentially simulating the Hamiltonian $H$ as $e^{-iHt}$. Hence you can see the resemblance here.

Comment: Thank you so much @KAJ226

Comment: @KAJ226 Are there any better methods for this specific case to simulate this Hamiltonian than the Trotter approximation?