# Simulate Hamiltonians with Pauli operations (controlled time evolution)

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, pauli-gates, linear-algebra

I had a question last week regarding the simulation of Hamiltonians composed of the sum of Pauli products: [How can I simulate Hamiltonians composed of Pauli matrices?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14507/how-can-i-simulate-hamiltonians-composed-of-pauli-matrices) I'm having a follow-up question: still for those two Hamiltonians:
$$
H_{1} = X_1+ Y_2 + Z_1\otimes Z_2
\\
H_{2} = X_1\otimes Y_2 + Z_1\otimes Z_2
$$
How can I perform the 'controlled version' of them? The thing really confused me is the 'tensor product term': for both $H_1$ and $H_2$, the two qubits are coupled, but if I want to do the controlled time-evolution simulation, should I couple the whole thing with the third qubit? If so, how to do that?

Thanks:)

Comment: The last post you used implicitly used exponentiation - do you want to use that approach or VQEs? (what's the end goal here might be a better question)

Comment: @C. Kang Thanks for the comment! I still prefer the exponentiation approach:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we know that $e^{i t H_2}$ has the following circuit:

[image]

From [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11406/9858) along with page 13 from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.3855) we can try to build the controlled-version of $e^{i t H_2}$ as follow:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Is there still a global phase gate needed on the control qubit?

Comment: The global phase gate is not needed if we don't have $e^{i I t}$ from my understanding. So unless our Hamiltonian is something like $H = XY + ZZ + II$ then you won't be needing it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!