# In quantum adiabatic simulation, is the $s$ in $(1-\frac{s}{T})H_{in}+\frac{s}{T} H_{cl}$ related to the $t$ in $e^{-iHt}$?

Tags: quantum-gate, optimization, annealing, quantum-circuit

I just want to do a whole adiabatic calculation on quantum circuit.
To prepare two Hamiltonian of $H_{initial}$ and $H_{classical}$ and solve $H_{classical}$ using adiabatic calc like quantum annealing.

The schedule is $H_s = (1-s/T)*H_{initial} + s/T*H_{classial}$

the time evolution operator is $e^{-iHt}$

Is the "$s$" on the schedule and the "$t$" in the operator related to each other?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is related, although you want to be careful. Strictly, $s$ is a function of time. This gives you the possibility to vary $\frac{ds}{dt}$ based on the gap $\delta_s$ between the ground and first excited states of $H_s$, and therefore control the accuracy of your adiabatic approximation. It's up to you how you pick it, but IIRC, it's nice to have
$$
\frac{ds}{dt}\sim\frac{1}{\delta_s}.
$$

So, yes, $s$ is function of time. However, you can no longer think of the evolution as $e^{-iHt}$ because that formula only applies if $H$ is independent of time, which $H_s$ now isn't. Instead, you have to go back to the Schrödinger equation
$$
\frac{d|\psi\rangle}{dt}=-iH_s|\psi\rangle
$$
and solve it. A reasonable approximation can be arrived at by thinking that $H_s$ is approximately constant over a set of intervals $\delta t_i$ so that you get a product
$$
\approx e^{-iH_{s_N}\delta t_N}\ldots e^{-iH_{s_2}\delta t_2} e^{-iH_{s_1}\delta t_1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Hermitian matrix, Hamiltonian, of the form $H = \sum_i H_i$. Then we can approximate $e^{-iHt}$ as follows:

$$ e^{-iHt} \approx  \prod_{j=1}^n \prod_i e^{-iH_i t/n} $$

This approximation is a consequence of the [Trotter product or also known as Lie product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_product_formula).

Now in term quantum circuit, it will be something like:

[image]

Then you somehow need to decompose each of the operator $e^{itH_i}$ into elementary gates. To do this step, look at this paper here: [Simulation of Electronic Structure Hamiltonians UsingQuantum Computers.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.3855.pdf) This [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11373/9858) by Davit is also really good reference to look at.