# Understanding QAOA from Basics/scratch

Tags: vqe, qaoa, adiabatic-model

Recently after working on QAOA with finance and graph coloring problems. I have started exploring the QAOA from scratch. I would like to understand the QAOA derivation mathematically and have started from [here](https://anonymousket.medium.com/qbasic-schrodinger-wave-equation-111a1ddeb340). But have no idea how to go further, could you please share any textbooks or references, which can guide me further.

Comment: Hello, personally I really like how QAOA is explained [here for the Qiskit Summer School 2021](https://learn.qiskit.org/summer-school/2021/lec5-2-introduction-quantum-approximate-optimization-algorithm-applications), there is also another [textbook version](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-applications/solving-combinatorial-optimization-problems-using-qaoa) which builds it from scratch

Comment: Thanks for your time and references @Lena,

Answer (score 1):

> Recently after working on QAOA with finance and graph coloring problems

Please have a look [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.15716), p.g. 20, for "user-friendly" explanation of QAOA. Disclaimer: I am author of the paper. The paper explores application of quantum algorithms in portfolio management, so it is probably connected with an area of your  interest.

> But have no idea how to go further, could you please share any textbooks or references, which can guide me further.

[Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4028) is a link to original paper by Farhi, Goldstone and Gutmann, where the QAOA has been firstly proposed.

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03719) paper, p.g. 41, you can find short description of QAOA with a description how it works on a particular example.

An finally some related discussion on this site [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/is-the-cost-hamiltonian-unitary-in-qaoa/17844#17844).

Comment: Thank you @Martin Vesely, will go through the references you have shared. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @anonymousKet: You are welcome.