# Simulating $e^{iX_1\otimes X_2t}$

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation

I'm trying to figure out the quantum circuit to simulate the time-evolution of a 2-qubit Hamiltonian $e^{iX_1\otimes X_2t}$, where $X$ is a Pauli gate. From [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11373/15562), the quantum circuit performs $e^{iZ_1\otimes Z_2t}$ could be constructed as an $R_z$ gate sandwiched by 2 controlled x gates. Can I replace $R_z$ by $R_x$ (and same goes for $R_y$) to simulate $e^{iX_1\otimes X_2t}$ and $e^{iY_1\otimes Y_2t}$? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just replace $R_z$ with $R_x$ - the $R_x$ would commute with the controlled-not, so the two controlled-nots cancel and all you get out is just the $R_x$.

The trick that you want to use instead is that $Ue^{-iHt}U^\dagger=e^{-iUHU^\dagger t}$. Now, we know that you can transform $Z\otimes Z$ into $X\otimes X$ using hadamards. So set $U$ to be the two-fold tensor product of Hadamards. Having said that, there are further circuit identities that you can use to simplify the circuit. You ultimately find that to get the $X\otimes X$ term, you need a circuit where you (i) replace the $R_z$ with $R_x$ and (ii) reverse the direction of the two controlled-nots.

You can follow a similar process to get $Y\otimes Y$ terms using
$$
U=\frac12(Z+Y)\otimes(Z+Y),
$$
but I'm not sure the circuit simplifies to the same extent.

Since you mention both $X\otimes X$ and $Y\otimes Y$ terms, I should point out that if the Hamiltonian that you *actually* want to simulate is $X\otimes X+Y\otimes Y$, you might be better off doing that directly rather than breaking it down into a pair of terms. What you need to think about is what is the unitary that diagonalises the term $X\otimes X+Y\otimes Y$, which is basically the inverse of the unitary that produces the Bell basis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I want to simulate $X\otimes X+Z\otimes Z$, then can I treat the two terms separately?

Comment: Can I append the circuit of $X\otimes X$ to the circuit of $Z\otimes Z$, and replace the two CNOT gates in the middle by a SWAP gate?

Comment: You *can* treat the two terms separately but if this is literally all you're doing, you'd be better treating them together as you'll be able to get away with fewer two-qubit gates.

Comment: You can append the two circuits, but a pair of controlled-nots is not a swap (unless you know that one of the input qubits is definitely 0). It's three controlled-nots that give swap.

Comment: I think it's sufficient to do the sequence cNOT - $R_x(\theta)\otimes R_z(\theta)$ - cNOT where the control is on the first qubit.

Comment: I just checked the two circuits and they are the same! Could you explain a bit about how to come up with the circuit?

Comment: You set $U$ to be the unitary that diagonalises your $H$. Then all you need is to implement $e^{-i D t}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, i.e. it's just going to require phase gates on the two qubits (and possibly a controlled-phase gate, but that turns out to not be necessary in this case)

Comment: It is also good to note that $RX(-\pi/2) \cdot Z \cdot RX(pi/2) = Y$ and so $\bigg( RX(-\pi/2)  \otimes RX(-\pi/2) \bigg) \cdot \bigg( Z \otimes Z \bigg) \otimes \bigg( RX(\pi/2) \otimes RX(\pi/2)  \bigg) = Y \otimes Y$.

Comment: As well as $(S\cdot H)\cdot Z \cdot (H \cdot S^\dagger ) = Y$ and hence  $(S\cdot H) \otimes (S\cdot H)  \cdot Z \otimes X \cdot (H \cdot S^\dagger ) \otimes (H \cdot S^\dagger ) = Y \otimes Y$