# Express $e^{i\frac{\gamma}{2}Z\otimes Z}$ in terms of CNOT and rotations gate

Tags: quantum-gate, pauli-gates

I have the Hamiltonian evolution operator for a two qubit system :

\begin{equation}
\hat{U}= e^{-i\gamma H}\;,\quad H = \frac{1}{2}(I - Z\otimes Z)
\end{equation}
where the $Z$ gate is applied on both qubits, ($I=I\otimes I$).

I would like to express this evolution operator in terms of CNOT gate and rotations.

I was told that $e^{i \frac{\gamma}{2}Z\otimes Z}$ could be decomposed as follows :
\begin{equation}
e^{i \frac{\gamma}{2}Z\otimes Z}=\text{CX}\;(I\otimes R_z(\gamma))\;\text{CX}\;,\quad R_z(\gamma) = e^{-i\frac{\gamma}{2}Z}
\end{equation}
where the CNOT gate operates on the second qubit each time (first qubit being the control one) and the rotation applies to the second one.

I found a related question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21269/showing-that-ei-sigma-z-otimes-sigma-z-t-textcnoti-otimes-ei-si) but I wonder if this can be simply demonstrated with the CNOT gate decomposition :
\begin{equation}
\text{CX}= e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}(I -Z)\otimes (I-X)}
\end{equation}

The development is the following :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{CX}\;(I\otimes e^{-i\frac{\gamma}{2}Z})\;\text{CX} &=
e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}(I -Z)\otimes (I-X)}\;(I\otimes e^{-i\frac{\gamma}{2}Z})\;
e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}(I -Z)\otimes (I-X)}\\
&=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}(I -Z)\otimes (I-X)}\;e^{-i\frac{\gamma}{2}I\otimes Z}\;
e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}(I -Z)\otimes (I-X)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Then, I am not sure how to proceed, it seems to me not trivial to
end up with $e^{i \frac{\gamma}{2}Z\otimes Z}$. This is the question. If the matrices within exponential do not commute, I don't think I can go further.

Comment: You seem to have already answered your own question, so what are you *actually* asking?

Comment: I tried to demonstrate the second formula by expanding CX gates with its decomposition in Pauli basis, but i was neither sure of the developments nor of if it is really achievable in this way. The related question I mentioned takes another way by using another expression of the CNOT gate.

Answer (score 1):

To verify the action of this circuit, I suggest computing how it acts on each of the 4 basis states $|00\rangle,|01\rangle,|10\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$.

For example
$$
|00\rangle\xrightarrow{CX}|00\rangle\xrightarrow{R_Z}e^{-i\gamma/2}|00\rangle\xrightarrow{CX}e^{-i\gamma/2}|00\rangle.
$$
Work this out for all 4 basis states. Is this consistent with what your gate is supposed to do?

---

You've asked for an algebraic method. While I don't entirely understand what is sought, here is another method...

Let $P_0=|0\rangle\langle 0|$ and $P_1=|1\rangle\langle 1|$. Then
$$
CX=P_0\otimes I+P_1\otimes X
$$
and
$$
I\otimes R_Z=(P_0+P_1)\otimes R_Z.
$$
It is important to recognise that $P_0P_1=0$. Hence, when I multiply together the 3 circuit elements, I get
$$
P_0\otimes R_Z+P_1\otimes(XR_ZX)=P_0\otimes R_Z+P_1\otimes(R_Z^\dagger)=\frac12(I+Z)\otimes R_Z+\frac12(I-Z)\otimes R_Z^\dagger
$$
Regroup the terms,
$$
I\otimes(R_Z+R_Z^\dagger)+Z\otimes (R_Z-R_Z^\dagger)=I\otimes I\cos(\gamma/2)-i\sin(\gamma/2)Z\otimes Z=e^{-i\gamma Z\otimes Z/2}
$$
but this all seems rather painful!

Comment: Yes, this is the way I was told the equality. My question was : is there an algebraic way to demonstrate this equality.

Comment: But what are the bounds on what you mean by that? Why not simply write out the matrices and multiply them?