# Confusion with the number of CNOTs in a circuit

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, gate-synthesis

I am a bit puzzled on the following circuit. According to [this Quantum Computing SE thread](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5567/circuit-construction-for-hamiltonian-simulation) it holds that
$$
e^{i(Z\otimes Z)t} = {\rm CNOT} (I\otimes e^{iZt}){\rm CNOT} \qquad (1)
$$

As a result we have the following circuit  (**C1**):[image]

Furthermore, for $e^{iZ\otimes Z\otimes Z t}$ we obtain the following circuit (**C2**):

[image]

I was reading arxiv:[2003.13599](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13599) and in Figure 3 we see three unitaries corresponding to $I\otimes Z \otimes I$, $I \otimes Z \otimes Z$ and $Z \otimes Z \otimes I$ seen below (**C3**):
[image]

Which is very confusing. Specifically, let's focus for example on the middle part of Diagram (a) corresponding to $I\otimes Z \otimes Z$. The $I$ term (in the first qubit) can be ignored. Then, if we ignore the first wire we essentially should have the term $Z\otimes Z$ from Eq. (1) but nevertheless we see two pairs of CNOT gates just like in (**C2**) that corresponds to $e^{iZ\otimes Z \otimes Z t}$.

**Why is this the case?** I suspect this is somehow related to the extra wire we ( **C2** has three wires but for some reason **C3** has four).

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. The middle part of Figure (a) here seems to be implementing the operation $I\otimes e^{i(Z\otimes Z\otimes Z)\theta_2}$.

Comment: I agree. But in the same diagram it is claimed this is $e^{i(I\otimes Z \otimes Z)\theta_2}$ that is two $Z$ gates and not 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the key fact you're missing is that $Z_2 \otimes Z_3 \otimes Z_4 = Z_2 \otimes Z_3$ when you know qubit 4 is in the $|0\rangle$ state; in the +1 eigenstate of $Z$.

I'm not sure why that paper is using six CNOT gates instead of four. The ancilla isn't helping. Maybe it's just supposed to be an example for a more general case where it *is* helpful.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand this precisely. Why use an ancilla state? 4 CNOTs should be enough.